# LINQ: Except doesn't work in the expected way

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, ado.net

I've problems to detect if there are new rows in a DataTable `Email_Total` that is yet not imported into `ContactDetail`.

```
Dim srcUnique = From row In src.Email_Total
                Select row.ticket_id, row.interaction, row.modified_time
Dim destUnique = From row In dest.ContactDetail
                Where row.ContactRow.ContactTypeRow.idContactType = emailContactTypeID
               Select row.ContactRow.Ticket_ID, row.Interaction, row.ModifiedAt
Dim diff = srcUnique.Except(destUnique)
Dim needUpdate = diff.Any
```

I have to compare the data on multiple columns because the ID is not equal in both tables.

This works until i've added `row.modified_time`/`row.ModifiedAt` columns(both DateTime) to the select, because rows are only unique if all three values are equal. If i add the the date-column as third argument the compiler shows following error(on `srcUnique.Except(destUnique)`):

*'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of `<anonymous type>`)' cannot be converted to 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of `<anonymous type>`)' because '`<anonymous type`> 
(line 471)' is not derived from '<`anonymous type`> (line 468)',  as required for the 'Out' 
generic parameter 'T' in 'Interface IEnumerable(Of Out T)'*

The strange thing is that the error is also shown when i remove the `row.Interaction`-column from the selects and leave only the `Ticket_ID` and `Modified_Time` but it works if i use the `Ticket_ID` and `Interaction` columns.

**Note**: `src` and `dest` are strong typed DataSets and the schema of both DataTables is slightly different, but i think that this issue is not only related to LINQ-to-DataSet.

**Edit**: these are the datamodels(Ticket_ID int,Interaction int, ModifiedAt DateTime)

[image]    [image]

**Solution**: (thanks to [@Stuart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731126/linq-except-doesnt-work-in-the-expected-way/6731277#6731277))

```
Dim srcUnique = From row In src.Email_Total
          Select Ticket_ID = row.ticket_id, Interaction = row.interaction, ModifiedAt = row.modified_time
Dim destUnique = From row In dest.ContactDetail
                Where row.ContactRow.ContactTypeRow.idContactType = emailContactTypeID
          Select row.ContactRow.Ticket_ID, row.Interaction, row.ModifiedAt
```

Comment: Your two types are different so linq cant compare them

Comment: @Manatherin: but the types of all columns are the same, hence i thought that linq would generate the same anonymous type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't speak VB... but in C# you'd need to make the spelling (including capitalization) and Types of all the property names are the same in order to get this to work:

i.e. this would fail

```
var srcUnique = from row in src.Email_Total
            select new { row.ticket_id, row.interaction, row.modified_time };
var destUnique = from row in dest.ContactDetail
            where row.ContactRow.ContactTypeRow.idContactType == emailContactTypeID
            select new { row.ContactRow.Ticket_ID, row.Interaction, row.ModifiedAt };
var diff = srcUnique.Except(destUnique);
```

but this would succeed:

```
var srcUnique = from row in src.Email_Total
            select new { Ticket_ID = row.ticket_id, Interaction = row.interaction, ModifiedAt = row.modified_time };
var destUnique = from row in dest.ContactDetail
            where row.ContactRow.ContactTypeRow.idContactType == emailContactTypeID
            select new { row.ContactRow.Ticket_ID, row.Interaction, row.ModifiedAt };
var diff = srcUnique.Except(destUnique);
```

(Assuming that the Types are the same)

Comment: How can i now get the complete rows of `Email_Total` according to the result of `srcUnique.Except(destUnique)`?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for - what is the "complete rows according to the result"? You want a lookup according to the Ticket_Id?

Comment: `diff` is a `IEnumerable(of <anonymous type>)`. But because i now want to import all the rows from `Email_Total` to `ContactDetail` that are new, i want to iterate these rows grouped by `Ticket_ID`. But `src.Email_Total.ToLookup(Function(row) row.ticket_id)` will group all rows and not only the new. `diff.ToLookup(Function(row) row.ticket_id)` will do what i want but then i only have the three columns(Ticket_Id,Interaction and ModifiedAt) and not all of table `Email_Total`.

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand or answer this in comments. I think what you need is to iterate over the {Ticket_Id, Interaction, ModifiedAt} keys - to use these to pull the full rows back into memory. If that's not waht you want, then it might be better to ask this again as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In the select list, the names, order and types of the variables must be the same.

Comment: I'm guessing that the foreign key, Ticket_ID, is nullable here.

Comment: @Lasse: Ticket_Id is not a foreign key. None of these are fk's but the `Ticket_ID` is not part `ContactDetail` but of a parent-table `Contact` associated via a fk `fiContact`. I don't think that this causes this issue because when i remove it from the select and leave only the two other columns, the error is the same. `fiContact`,`Ticket_Id`(of Table `Contact`) and `ticket_id` of the source-table `Email_Total` are all not nullable.